# Android MPandroidchart Plotting is not in sync with real time

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidchart to plot a real time line graph.I have 240 values in a second to be plotted. But the plotting is too slow and it takes more than 5 seconds to plot the data of a second. How is it possible to do the plotting of 1 second data in one second itself?

```
private void addEntryGraph1() {
LineData data = graph1.getLineData();
if (data != null) {
    ILineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
    if (set == null) {
        set = createSet();
        data.addDataSet(set);
    }
    data.addXValue(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
            .format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    for (int i = 0; i < sampleRatio; i++)
        data.addEntry(new Entry((float) (ch1Buffer.get(i)), set.getEntryCount()), 0);
    graph1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    graph1.setVisibleXRange(240, 240);
    graph1.moveViewToX(0);
    synchronized (ch1Buffer) {
        ch1Buffer.subList(0, sampleRatio).clear();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I recommended creating an issue[Help or question] on github. https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: I have created already. The issue number is #1676

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library is not feasible for large amount of data to be plotted at realtime. Confirmed by Philipp Jahoda.

Please find the answer in github
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1676